# JAVA class hierarchy: Which of the following lines will not compile?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, hierarchy

Having the following class hierarchy:

```
Interface Animal {…}
class Dog implements Animal{…}
class Poodle extends Dog {…}
class Labrador extends Dog {…}
```

Which of the following lines will not compile?

```
Poodle poodle = new Poodle(); //1
Animal animal = (Animal) poodle; //2
Dog dog = new Labrador(); //3
animal = dog; //4
poodle = dog; //5
Animal labrador = new Labrador(); //6
Dog dog2 = new Labrador(); //7
dog 2=labrador;//8
```

I think line 5: because of poodle's and dog's static binding.

Line  8 : only static binding is relevant for an assignment  .

Am I right? May you give an explanation?

Comment: The point of the instructor asking you this question is for **you** to answer it, based on research. Asking other people to answer it for you is not research. Even if you post your own partial answer.

Comment: it is  for the test review

Comment: To add to TJ's comment, you could try compiling the code and then see what is failing and which error you get.

Comment: You are right, it's 5. I am not sure if a meaningful answer is possible here, so you may want to delete the question. After all, your instructor may not be new to Stack Overflow :-)

Comment: I also said line 8: is it right too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, statements 5 and 8  are going to fail.

5> You cannot assign a parent class' object to a child class' ref variable. *A poodle is definitely a dog. But a dog may not be a Poodle.*

8> Same holds true for line 8 as well. This, however, would be okay: `dog2= (Dog)labrador;`

Note: The explicit typecasting done in line 8 would be okay, since labrador is the object of Labrador, which is further a subclass of Dog. If you try to do the same in the case of (5), like

```
poodle = (Poodle)dog;
```

it would compile but would fail at runtime - because of the simple reason - `dog` refers to a Labrador. `dog.getClass()` would return `Labrador.class`. For this object to be referred by any ref, the ref should be that of a class/interface that belongs in the upward hierarchy of the object's original class. *A labrador, though being a dog, is definitely not a poodle.*

Also, The explicit typecasting done is Line 2 isn't very useful, since it is done implicitly. The following is where an explicit typecase would be required:

```
Dog d = new Labrador();
Labrador lbd = (Labrador) d;
```

Comment: Why no casting will help with line 5?

Comment: Added some edits. This should help you. Why would someone downvote my answer? :P Atleast have the humility to add a comment if you are doing so..

Comment: Thanks! What 'ref' stands for?

Comment: Reference variable. You can refer the _object_ of a class using the _reference variable_ of itself or a parent class.

Comment: Learn the concepts of Polymorphism in java. They are absolutely a must if you are a java programmer. Concepts regarding Static and dynamic binding step in later.

Comment: Doesn't  static and dynamic binding  important here? When referring to dog's parent class you look at the static binding, don't you?

Comment: http://www.javatpoint.com/static-binding-and-dynamic-binding This should help you understand the concept. But I suggest you go through basic polymorphism first.

Comment: at line 2: it's not necessarily to make a casting **(Animal)**, right?

Comment: correct. that's done automatcally. Adding an edit for you..